# Maximum numbers of users in CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

Is there any limit to add users in `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP`?

In Unix/Linux, you can add only up to 32.
Is there any limit on this in windows ClearCase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [IBM article](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21131881):

> ClearCase does enforce a limitation on the number of ClearCase groups a user may belong to.
>
> **The `SUNRPC` protocol that we use can process a maximum of 32 groups on Windows and 16 groups on Unix.
>
>   This means that users in an all Windows environment can have a maximum of 32 groups that can use ClearCase and 16 groups in an all Unix environment or a Windows and Unix interop environment**.
>
> By default, ClearCase will recognize only the first 32 groups of a user's group list as displayed by the output of the **[`creds` utility](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?&rs=984&uid=swg21221403)** on Windows.
>   The total of 32 groups includes the Windows primary group or `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` variable and the next 31 groups either from the `creds` output or from the `CLEARCASE_GROUPS` variable.
>
> The environment variables, [`CLEARCASE_GROUPS`](http://www-1.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?&rs=984&uid=swg21124574) and [`CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP`](http://www-1.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?&rs=984&uid=swg21135509), can help to resolve or alleviate some of the issues that may arise due to this limitation.

Comment: Suppose there are total 60 people in CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP and I want to add more people in it but theese people are already there in CLEARCASE_GROUPS, will it make any different to add or not to add?

Comment: @user2370590 no the limit is for the number of groups a user can be in, not the limit of users you can add in a group. Plus, you don't have to add people to `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP`: it is a user environment variable which is set by a user to reference only **one** group: the one that ClearCase will consider as the "primary" one for that user, and which references one of the Windows group that user is registered in. One of the *32* groups, that is, since the limitation (again) is about the numbers of groups a user is registered in.